# Ngingx wont start with fastcgi_split_path_info" error

Tags: nginx

I heard that nginx is faster and since im on a VPS with low ram i thought id try it out.

I got through this tutorial http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-php-5.3-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-debian

But I now get the following error:

unknown directive "fastcgi_split_path_info" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:28

Anyone know what might be causing the problem? I cant find any reference to the problem on Google

Also I have heard conflicting things about Nginx vs Apache. Some say use one, some say the other. Im using allsorts such as rewrite rules, proxies etc. Am I setting myself up for a fall by using Nginx?

If I go for apache, does anyone know of anyway to tweak it so that it performs better on a low ram VPS?

Cheers Ke

Comment: I have also tried that tutorial. I failed but not with the same error: http://serverfault.com/questions/122316/how-have-i-locked-me-out-from-my-ubuntu-vps

Answer (score 1):

Because your repository uses an outdated version of nginx.

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_split_path_info

As the manual states fastcgi_split_path_info requires >= 0.7.31 and your repo most likely ships 0.6.x.

Nginx has such rapid development that most default repos fail. Compile from source or find a repo that keeps it updated.